# connecting simulink conservation ports to simulink blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to connect simple electrical components to normal simulink blocks such as flip flops, matlb function blocks etc. However, is there a way to interface the conservative ports to the simulink components? I know we can use PS converter to convert the physical signals to simulink signals. But, what do we use to connect the conservative signals to the normal simulink blocks?

Comment: See the below answer - you can use the PS converter to convert to a physical signal, then use a sensor to convert that physical signal to an electrical type (ie. voltage, current, or resistance), or any other type of non-standard physical signal you require. If you're looking for the reverse direction, use a sensor (ie. voltage sensor, current sensor) to convert to a physical signal, then the PS converter to convert to a normal simulink signal

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly connect a physical port to a standard Simulink port. Physical ports are not directional, unlike standard Simulink ports, and conserve energy that is exchanged through the port. The only way to interface physical parts of a Simulink models with standard Simulink signals is through the [PS-Simulink Converter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/pssimulinkconverter.html) and [Simulink-PS Converter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html) blocks. These are typically use for sensor or actuator signals.

Comment: @anusual - I agree with this answer and it should answer your question. Please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when the OP says "PS Converter" they are referring to the PS-Simulink and Simulink-PS converters. Those work for the generic physical signals - number + unit.

The question, I believe, is more specifically about energy **conserving** signals, which are another step above generic physical signals. There are two general types: electrical and mechanical. Also, in addition to general mechanical signals, there are additional types of mechanical conserving signals including: Gas, Hydraulic, Isothermal Liquid, and Magnetic. The key parts of these conserving signals is they have two properties - an "across" property and a "through" property (e.g. voltage and current for electrical).

This one perplexed me for a bit, too. The tricky thing is, to convert conserving ports / signals to physical ports / signals you need a specific "sensor" for exactly the type of signal you need. Each kind has it's own set of "sensors" that can be used to translate them to generic physical signals, then the `PS-Simulink` and `Simulink-PS` converters can be used on those resulting physical signals to translate to "normal" (unitless) Simulink signals.

They work like "real life" sensors in that they measure these properties and translate them to a signal that can be used by something else - but since it's Simulink and not real life, they can do more than real life sensor signals as they can be used as values that can drive other processes within Simulink with physical or standard Simulink blocks (by adding PS-Simulink Converters) providing an interface between Simscape and "normal" Simulink.

If you search for "sensor" in the library browser, hopefully you can find the ones you need for your specific application. Each one will require two conserving inputs and will output a single physical signal. Here is a list of the ones I know of, by type and location in the library browser in MATLAB R2022b:

## Electrical Signals:

### Simscape / Foundation Library / Electrical / Electrical Sensors /:

- `Voltage Sensor` - Creates 1-D physical signal with units of Volts for a single voltage difference between two points [Also available under Simscape / Foundation Library / Electrical Sensors]
- `Current Sensor` - Creates 1-D physical signal with units of Amps for a single current [Also available under Simscape / Foundation Library / Electrical Sensors]

### Simscape / Electrical / Sensors & Transducers / (Must have Simscape Electrical Toolkit)

- `Voltage Sensor` (same as above)
- `Current Sensor` (same as above)
- `Line Voltage Sensor (Three-Phase)`* - Creates a 3-D physical signal with units of Volts representing the 3 line-to-line voltages across each set of lines
- `Phase Voltage Sensor (Three-Phase)`* - Creates a 3-D physical signal with units of Volts representing the 3 phase voltages across each line and ground
- `Current Sensor (Three-Phase)`* - Creates a 3-D physical signal with units of Amps representing the 3 phase currents between two 3-phase nodes
- `Current and Voltage Sensor (Three-Phase)`* - Creates two 3-D physical signals, one with units of Amps, one with units of volts, representing the 3-phase currents between two 3-phase nodes and either the "phase-to-phase" (aka "line" - I wish they would have worded it "line-to-line" instead) voltage or the "phase-to-ground" (aka "phase") voltage.

*Note: Each Three-Phase sensor has an option to take a "composite" input of all three phases or to and "expanded" input with one input for each phase. For tje current sensors, that also affects the outputs.

## Mechanical Signals:

### Simscape / Foundation Library / Mechanical / Mechanical Sensors /:

- `Ideal Force Sensor` - Creates a physical signal from force pass through
- `Ideal Rotational Motion Sensor` - Creates one or more physical signals representing acceleration, angular velocity, and/or position.
- `Ideal Torque Sensor` - Creates a physical signal from torque pass through
- `Ideal Translational Motion Sensor` - Creates one or more physical signals representing acceleration, velocity, and/or position.

### Simscape / Foundation Library / Gas / Sensors /:

- `Mass & Energy Flow Rate Sensor(G)` - Outputs 2 physical signals for mass flow rate and energy flow rate through
- `Pressure & Temperature Sensor (G)` - Outputs 2 physical signals for temperature and pressure difference between two physical points
- `Thermodynamic Properties Sensor (G)` - Outputs one or more physical signals for specific enthalpy, density, specific heat at constant pressure, and specific entropy
- `Volumetric Flow Rate Sensor (G)` - Outputs a physical signal for the volumetric flow rate through

### Simscape / Foundation Library / Hydraulic / Hydraulic Sensors /:

- `Hydraulic Flow Rate Sensor` -  Outputs two physical signals for volumetric flow rate and mass flow rate through
- `Hydraulic Pressure Sensor` - Outputs a physical signal for the hydraulic pressure differential between two points

### Simscape / Foundation Library / Isothermal Liquid / Sensors /:

- `Flow Rate Sensor (IL)` -  Outputs two physical signals for volumetric flow rate and mass flow rate through
- `Liquid Properties Sensor (IL)` - Outputs physical signals for mixture density, bulk modulus, and fraction of entrained air
- `Pressure Sensor (IL)` - Outputs a physical signal that can be configured for absolute pressure, differential pressure, or gauge pressure

### Under Simscape / Foundation Library / Magnetic / Magnetic Sensors /:

- `Flux Sensor` - Outputs a physical signal for the magnetic flux between two points in a magnetic circuit (similar to current sensor)
- `MMF Sensor` - Outputs a physical signal for the magnetomotiveforce difference between two points in a magnetic circuit (similar to voltage sensor)

I imagine, if you have the Simscape Fluids or Simscape Multibody toolboxes, there may be more sensors available similar to the Simscape Electrical toolbox. If you can't find one you're looking for, search "sensor" in the library browser.

These will only work to measure the specific types of ports they are designed to work with, so you have to choose the correct one for the application.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. I've been searching for a way to convert a double into a voltage, and the solution was basically what you mentioned above: there is a sensor "PS Sensor" which converts an input physical signal to an electrical signal, of resistance, voltage, or current. So all I needed was the physical signal converter above, then the "PS Sensor" which converted that to a voltage. Thanks!! I've been struggling with this problem for a long time

Answer (score 0):

The problem withe the conservative ports that you're mentioning here is that in a sense, they contain multiple signals. For an electrical network, do you want to extract the voltage or the current? Because both would essentially be passing through the conservative port. The typical approach here would be to place a sensor (Simscape/Foundation Library/Electrical/Electrical Sensors) in line with your conservative port to capture the signal you want and then connect a PS-Simulink block to the output of from the sensor.